# How to find empty files and edit the header of them. by find and echo

Tags: linux, bash, awk, find, echo

I have a folder contains ~30000 files and some of them are empty. I want to find them and put 'NON' as a header of the empty files.

my script is:

```
 find -type f -empty -exec echo 'NON' {} \;
```

my output is:

```
 NON ./file1
 NON ./file2
 NON ./file3
 NON ./file4
```

but I want the 'NON' to write as a header of the file1 , file2 , file3 and file4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want your zero length files to now contain the text NON, right? Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just echo `NON` first and then do your `find`, with no need for `exec`?

Also I am not sure how you are running `find` without specifying a directory to search, so I have added the current directory to search below.

```
 echo 'NON'
 find . -type f -empty
```

The other possible interpretation of your question is that you want to add the string `NON` to all zero-length files. You can do that like this.

```
find . -type f -empty -exec sh -c "echo NON > {}" \;
```

Comment: +1 I think the second interpretation is the correct one.